# Error while fetching server API version:('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a python script that checks logs of a docker container, and given the necessary conditions, restarts it. But I'm facing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    if container.check_container_logs():
  File "/usr/src/app/RestartContainer/RestartDockerContainer.py", line 11, in check_container_logs
    client = docker.from_env()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 94, in from_env
    return cls(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 220, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

I checked that docker service is running, added my user to docker group, verified that `docker.sock` file exists, but nothing works. Could you help me?
I'm using a remote server with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b and Python 3.10.10 slim-bullseye for the container.

Thi is my code:

```
import docker
import datetime

class RestartDockerContainer:
    def __init__(self, container_name, error_keywords):
        self.container_name = container_name
        self.error_keywords = error_keywords


    def check_container_logs(self):
        client = docker.from_env()
        container = client.containers.get(self.container_name)
        logs = container.logs().decode('utf-8').split('\n')[-300:]
        for keyword in self.error_keywords:
            if keyword in logs:
                return True
        return False

    def get_last_log_timestamp(self):
        client = docker.from_env()
        container = client.containers.get(self.container_name)
        logs = container.logs().decode('utf-8').split('\n')
        if logs:
            last_log = logs[-2] 
            timestamp_str = last_log.split(' ')[0]
            try:
                timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
                return timestamp
            except ValueError:
                return None
        return None

    def restart_container(self):
        client = docker.from_env()
        container = client.containers.get(self.container_name)
        container.restart()
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  restart-container-1:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxxx/yyyyyy/restart-container:prod-1.0.0
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: restart-container-1
    environment:
    - CLIENT=m1-1
    - PROFILE=prod
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 500M
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-size: 40m
        max-file: '2'
```

Comment: drive-by comment (with apologies in advance): I suspect you need to mount `docker.sock` into your container in order for it to be able to interact with the API (provided by `docker.sock`). You'd need to add a `volumes` (list) under `restart-container-1` at the same level as e.g. `environment` and `- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`